# How with additive done method in controller use custom method in policy?

Tags: laravel

Reading docs at https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#authorizing-resource-controllers I added policy to Task model:

```
class TaskController extends Controller
{
    protected CrudRepositoryInterface $taskCrudRepository;
    protected DBTransactionInterface $dbTransaction;

    public function __construct(CrudRepositoryInterface $taskCrudRepository, DBTransactionInterface $dbTransaction)
    {
        $this->authorizeResource(Task::class, 'task');
    }
```

and it works ok for all viewAny, view, create, create, update, update, delete methods, which are referenced in the docs above.
But I need to add additive done method into controller with custom method in policy, like :

```
/**
 * Set status DONE to the specified Task model
 *
 * @param int $taskId
 *
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function done(Task $task): JsonResponse
{
    \Log::info(varDump($task, ' -1 done $task::')); // I see this message in log file
    $this->authorize('done', [auth()->user(), Task::class]);

    try {
        $task = $this->taskCrudRepository->done(id: $task->id);

    ...
```

and in policy app/Policies/TaskPolicy.php file :

```
/**
 * Determine whether the user can update the model.
 *
 * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
 * @param  \App\Models\Task  $task
 * @return \Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response|bool
 */
public function update(?User $user, Task $task)
{
    return $this->getPolicyRule(user: $user, policyOperation: PolicyOperation::UPDATE, task: $task);
}

/**
 * Determine whether the user can done the model.
 *
 * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
 * @param  \App\Models\Task  $task
 * @return \Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response|bool
 */
public function done(?User $user, Task $task)
{
    \Log::info(varDump($task->id, ' -12 done TaskPolicy $task->id::')); ; // I DO NOT see this message in log file
    return $this->getPolicyRule(user: $user, policyOperation: PolicyOperation::DONE, task: $task);
}
```

But I got error message :

```
This action is unauthorized
```

How correctly to use done method of policy?

Comment: Check $task, not Task::class

Comment: Do you mean in "done" controller action instead of ' $this->authorize('done', [auth()->user(), Task::class]);` to write `$this->authorize('done', [auth()->user(),  $task]);` ? I tried but the same `This action is unauthorized` error of method of policy class is not called